# Overridden toString not called

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When trying to call `toString` of the following class then `Object.toString` is called and `[object Object]` is printed to the console. Why is `Bankaccount.toString` not called?

```
export class Bankaccount {
  name: string;
  iban: string;
  bic: string;
  accountNumber: string;
  customerId: string;
  type: string;
  id?: number;

  constructor(name: string, iban: string, bic: string, accountNumber?: string, customerId?: string, type?: string, id?: number) {
    this.name = name;
    this.iban = iban;
    this.bic = bic;
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    this.customerId = customerId;
    this.type = type;
    this.id = id;
  }

  toString = (): string => {
    return 'Bankaccount[Name: ' + this.name + ', IBAN: ' + this.iban + ', BIC: ' + this.bic + ', Typ: ' + this.type + ']';
  }

}
```

The caller/client:

```
import {Bankaccount} from '../../models/model-interfaces';
... further imports ...

@Component({
  selector: 'ac-bankaccount-edit',
  templateUrl: './bankaccount-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bankaccount-edit.component.css']
})
export class BankaccountEditComponent {

  bankaccount: Bankaccount = new Bankaccount('BankName', 'IBAN1234', 'BIC9876', '', '', 'PRIVATE');

  constructor() {}

  logBankaccount() {
    console.log('BA1: ' + this.bankaccount);
    console.log('BA2: ' + this.bankaccount.toString());
    console.log(`${this.bankaccount}`);
  }

}
```

Comment: Try by just printing console.log(this.bankaccount);

Comment: Where do you create instance of class: `Bankaccount?`

Comment: @Karabah `bankaccount = new Bankaccount(...)`

Comment: Do you need to declare `toString` as public?

Comment: Your code is working on StackBlitz as is. All three versions log `Bankaccount[Name: BankName, IBAN: IBAN1234, BIC: BIC9876, Typ: PRIVATE]`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-86am6k

Comment: @StriplingWarrior Class members (properties & methods) are public by default